# How to identify between new or existing account record in trigger when a lead is converted?

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion, sales-cloud

During the lead conversion process inside the trigger, I want to identify whether the converted account is new or existing.

I need to identify when users select whether to Create New or Choose Existing accounts record in the trigger. see in the below picture.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: Hi Mayank, can you also add the things you have tried so far?

Comment: Pleas include the relevant code you have created so far and what else you have tried. See [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the account insert trigger executed, and if so, you know it was a new account.

```
public class AccountFlags {
  public static Boolean hasInsertRun = false;
}
```

...

```
trigger on Account (after insert) {
  AccountFlags.hasInsertRun = true;
}
```

...

```
trigger on Lead (after update) {
  for(Integer i = 0, s = Trigger.new.size(); i < s; i++) {
    if(!Trigger.old[i].IsConverted && Trigger.new[i].IsConverted) {
      if(AccountFlags.hasInsertRun) {
        // This was a new account
      } else {
        // Existing account
      }
    }
  }
}
```